# VS2015 : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, udp

I wrote a code on Visual studio 2015 for a windows 10 PC. The application is mainly focused on UDP communication and I use the boost libraries.
It works perfectly but when I move the folder of the code to Windows 7 I receive the error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)". I tried also in Windows 8.1 and after rebuilding the libraries it works.

What I noticed is that when I receive the error it does not load the .dll that in the other versions it loads.

May it be a problem with the boost?
Have you ever experienced it?

Comment: Is the .dll you're using the same? Did you compile the program on Windows 7, or are you just dragging a binary around?

Comment: The .dll are internal in Windows. I do not explicitly include them in the project.

Comment: Depending on how you're linking these, you'll at least need to have a header which defines the interface, if not a .lib to build against. Have you ensured that these are consistent on Windows 7?

Answer (score 9):

0xc000007b is error when you try to use x64 dlls in x32 application or other way around, so you probably copied wrong dlls. Rebuild fixed this, as it prepared new dlls.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. If you could provide a source that would make an excellent answer.

Comment: Here is old thread on support: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when?forum=vssetup In general it has broader meaning than just x32/x64 mismatch, but unless your dll is corrupted that's the best call.

Comment: :( Anything more conclusive? There's not even an accepted answer here, and there are a lot of answers that suggest this is *not* a 64/32-bit problem.

Comment: I did not include any dll in my project. If I try to follow the process in the link, I tried to install devenv and if I run devenv with Dependency Walker I receive an error (At least one file was not a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module)

Comment: Moreover, I cannot substitute the .dll . Even if I take the ownership, Windows says the .dll is currently used in a process (that obviously I cannot control)

Comment: I don't have any more spec for this, even though I've searched a lot. This error says "bad image", which basically means that dll exists, but your app is unable to load it. At work we switch OSes a lot (for the same app), and x32/x64 was only time we had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

***win7_64 visual studio 2015, 0xc000007b***
When I was programming C++ code in the visual studio 2015, it threw the error:0x000007b, and I have tried three kinds of solutions;
1.Installing Direct X
2.Installing VC C++ 2015 libraries
3.Making sure the DLL is consistent with the OS(and I think this is relevant to my problem)
ANd my solution will show below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2T6v.jpg)

and I changed the [[[Debug]]] into [[[X64]]], then, it works, I believe that because some dlls are not consistent with the platform, so if I changed the Debug platform, We will get the correct result.The prerequisite：must having installed all dlls under the X64 system.