# How to determine what is causing Application error 0xc000007b?

Tags: c++

I have an application that is working very well on my computer. On the other hand, after releasing it, someone reported it is having error 0xc000007b.

My application is build using Visual Studio 2015, and has both x64 and x32 builds.

What is the best way to answer him, when I do not know what Operating System he is using?

How can I ask him to track this issue he has, when he is the only one reporting this error?

Comment: maybe your executable doesn't have the right rights

Comment: 0xc000007b - INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT - 1st guess trying to run a 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2015 : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307379/vs2015-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [0xc000007b error in running a c++ made program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477721/0xc000007b-error-in-running-a-c-made-program)

Comment: Thanks for your answer he did not say what his system does he has

Comment: How can I tell hem to track his issue while he is the only one reporting this issue

Comment: *How can I ask him to track this issue* -- You need to give us more information about your application.  Does it use third-party DLL's, where the names of the DLL's in both 32 and 64-bit have the same name?  If so, Windows will attempt to load the first DLL it encounters with that name -- it doesn't do a check if the DLL is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: I did add all dll needed to run the application for both x64 and x32 and I did test it before releasing it in new computers 7,8,8.1 and 10 and it is working fine is both system 32 and 64 even I had to make sure he does not have to install VC 2015

Comment: @ABDULRAHMANALKHAMEES Why are you testing this on your computer?  You should be investigating your user's computer, no?  I bet his `PATH` is pointing to the 32-bit DLL's and the user is running the 64-bit version, or vice-versa.  That error is the classic one when Windows loads the wrong DLL, but that DLL just happens to have the same name as the one you really want to load.

Comment: No one ever Reported this error before While my application released more than two years ago and he did not say which operating System he has or Which App his running on the hand he might be running on operating system earlier than win 7 I guess...?

Comment: You should state to the customer what the minimum operating system is that your application should run on.  Second, any application developer would have some sort of logging or some sort of system to diagnose user's issues, and especially if you're going to distribute the application to who-knows.   Getting operating system information could be easily done by contacting the person and doing a sysinfo or similar, or your application contains a program that collects this information.  You can't rely just on your local testing and then hope for the best.

Comment: *No one ever Reported this error before While my application released more than two years ago* -- Sorry, but this type of reasoning is what gets a programmer fired from his job.  If you release an application to the general public, you must *always* expect something may go wrong, regardless of when it was released.  That's the nature of the programming business.

Comment: I did Ask him about the operating System his running and Some other information and he did not reply as you said before I guess he was running the x64 on his operating system which is could be 32. I think this only Issue he could has... Thanks for your answers...

Comment: OK, you should wait for the reply,  Probably he is running the x64 version on a 32-bit OS, or he has both versions installed for whatever reason, and there is a mixup in the PATH somewhere.

Comment: I'll Wait for him to reply, Thanks for great discussion....